# Criminal manages to cross state border before Superman gets to him, but is caught in a twist

Tags: story-identification, dc, superman

This one, I didn't read. I got it narrated to me by a friend, who found the ending twist rather amusing. Maybe it isn't even a comic. Fleischer cartoon? George Reeves TV series? Well, anyway. The criminal gets Superman distracted somehow while he flees, and Superman eventually finds him *just* as he crossed the state border, so he can't be arrested anymore. The criminal gloats, and since he's a skilled gunslinger type, he throws a coin into the air and shoots a hole into it. Superman then flies past the border and grabs the criminal.

> – Hey, you can't arrest me! I'm past the border!
> – Destroying money is a **federal** crime. You're under arrest.

It was told to me circa 1990, but it could have been as far back as the 1940s. Of course, since it is a retelling, the dialogue was probably not exactly that.

Comment: [The Rider](https://digitalcomicmuseum.com/preview/index.php?did=4501&page=33) punched a guy over the State border

Comment: Is shooting a coin a federal crime in the US?

Comment: @NomadMaker Don't know if it's a reliable source but this says yes https://www.thoughtco.com/is-burning-money-illegal-3367953

Comment: @NomadMaker From that article: "Because the Federal Reserve has to replace any money taken out of circulation, and it costs anywhere from about 5.5 cents to make a $1 bill to about 14 cents for a $100 bill." Stronger anti-counterfeiting measures, I suppose. Otherwise the cost should be exactly the same.

Comment: Destroying US coins is illegal only if done with fraudulent intent, like coin shaving or counterfeiting.  Destroying US bills is illegal despite the intent, but the law primarily exists to combat counterfeiting, so if you're not counterfeiting (or running a scam like the half-20) you're unlikely to be prosecuted.  In reality, destroying cash allows the government to print more cash, which will then be in their possession, so it works out to be a voluntary tax in the long run.  The Rider, since he shot a coin but not for fraudulent purposes, is in the clear legally.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

*Superman* #153 (1962).

> SHERIFF: Consarn it! Since Finch has not committed a federal offense, I can't legally go after him! All I can do now is notify the proper authorities, but by that time he'll be gone! [...]
>
> SUPERMAN *(tosses coin)*: Finch! Look at this coin! See how it glitters! Keep your eyes on it!
>
> FINCH *(shoots coin)*: I'm wise to you! You're tryin to hypnotize me into giving myself up! There - now that coin won't stop me!
>
> SUPERMAN *(grabs villain)*: Wrong, Finch! The coin did get you after all! It's a federal offense to mutilate any U.S. coin!

[image: Superman outwits a criminal]

---

Found with the Google query `dc superman arrests criminal at state border site:dc.fandom.com`.

Comment: Silver Age comics were strange, that is certain.

Comment: That last panel is also ... something.

Comment: @Adamant how to make any comic into a 60s-style comic: 1/ end all narration boxes with "..." 2/ end all spoken-out sentences with exclamation marks.

Comment: @Jenayah: Wow! You're right! *I never even noticed that before you pointed it out...*

Comment: Questions that I have after reading this: 1) Does Superman know that it's only an offence to *fraudulently* mutilate a coin? 2) Does either Finch or Superman know that you can pursue a criminal over state lines? 3) Are there places where the state line is actually labeled by a stripe on the road and a little post? 4) Was Superman *actually able to hypnotize him* with the coin? 5) Does Superman think hypnotizing someone across state lines is more legal than arresting them? 6) Why did Finch choose to shoot the coin once he already was no longer looking at it?

Comment: 7) How was Finch able to shoot the coin so accurately? 8) Does the writer think it's acceptable to waste taxpayer money on a show trial that doesn't even result in prison?

Comment: @Adamant On your third point, not that I know of but most road crossings of state borders in the US do have very prominent signage marking the state borders. On your seventh point, given the apparent distance between Finch and the coin and the apparent size of the coin, that's a tricky shot but not unreasonably so if the shooter is particularly skilled and has a good gun.

Comment: @Adamant, it's not like all trials result in a prison sentence anyway, is it? And a _show trial_ that did result in prison would be even more questionable.

Comment: @Adamant: 3) [Baarle-Nassau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baarle-Nassau). :-D (I know you meant US state, but that one is too good to not bring up. ;-) )

Comment: @DevSolar People living there have some really weird moments this year, with all the differences between Belgium and Netherlands anti-coronavirus rules.

Comment: Man, that's a tiny bullet.

Comment: @Adamant On your fifth point, I assumed while reading the excerpt that Superman was not actually hypnotizing Finch, but only leading Finch to think he was, fully expecting him to shoot the coin (a Batman Gambit, if you will). Had Superman already demonstrated an ability to hypnotize?

Comment: @LeeC. [yes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/131207/98028)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Or a really big coin.

Comment: I like how there is a literal line on the road where the state line is.

Comment: Does Superman have jurisdiction anywhere?

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim [yes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/29095/98028) (kinda)